# Does a magic packet need to be sent on a specific port for it to work?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have read that one would need to send a WOL (wake on lan) magic packet on port 7 or 9 of the target machine (with WOL enabled in H/W) for it to work.

Is this correct? If not, then how is the WOL packet processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic packet is necessarily not a packet at all, it must consist of a Frame, so it just needs a valid payload that contains the magic string. you can put a packet and a segment in it, but they are not actually processed by the IP and TCP/UDP layers.

> From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet:
>
> The magic
>   packet is a broadcast frame containing anywhere within its payload 6
>   bytes of all 255 (FF FF FF FF FF FF in hexadecimal), followed by
>   sixteen repetitions of the target computer's 48-bit MAC address, for a
>   total of 102 bytes.
>
> Since the magic packet is only scanned for the string above, and not
>   actually parsed by a full protocol stack, it may be sent as any
>   network- and transport-layer protocol, although it is typically sent
>   as a UDP datagram to port 7 or 9, or directly over Ethernet as
>   EtherType 0x0842.

so the answers to your questions are no and yes respectively. you do not need to use an upper layer protocol at all, the IP paccket need not be addressed to the target machine, and the ports don't actually listen or recieve the WOL datagram at all; the Datalink layer scans the payload for the magic string, and if found does not pass the payload up to the Network layer for processing at all. Many implementations use UDP\7 (Echo) and UDP\9 (Discard), probably so that systems which do not support WOL do not process the packet in a potentially unsafe way. On those systems the upper layers would receive the segment.

Note however that while WOL is implemented 100% in hardware and drivers, its compliance varies from vendor to vendor and device to device, so it is often finicky.

Comment: `the Datalink layer scans the payload for the magic string, and if found does not pass the payload up to the Network layer for processing at all.` it can not just "drop" packages, if them contains magic string, because it absolutely valid for upper layer protocol to have that sequence of bytes as part of payload.

Comment: @PetSerAl, feel free to argue your point over at wikipedia if you like. I'm guessing your concern is likley why many implementations make it point to the UDP Echo port (7), or the UDP "Discard" port (9), or even better using a raw frame directed at LLC 0x0842, but those upper layer ports do nothing with the data, and do nothing in themselves to support WOL. I am thinking they do this so that WOL traffic to non-WOL capable systems is non-disruptive. Like the Frame, the IP datagram would be a LAN broadcast.

Comment: First, I does not find at Wikipedia anything that support your claim (`if found does not pass the payload up to the Network layer for processing at all.`). Second, when computer sleep, no Network layer processing should be going, so no packets passed to Network layer regardless of have them correct WoL pattern or not. Third, on my WoL capable and configured computer, I am able to receive packets that have correct WoL pattern, so them are not dropped by Datalink layer.

Comment: ummm, that's what `Since the magic packet is only scanned for the string above, and not actually parsed by a full protocol stack` means. Look into sleep states. sleep is not like hibernate, and leaves the computer able to wake itself on a schedule, and on events like receiving a frame. WOL is a standard, and yes some implementers may do it differently, but the intention of the protocol is to handle everything at Layer 2, and not involve higher layers of the network stack.

Comment: @FrankThomas you mentioned in your answer that it needs a broadcast frame. The application I was using to generate the WOL packet was asking me if I want to broadcast or to use specific destination of my hibernating PC. I was always putting the specific (not broadcast) router ip address where I port forward the WOL packets to my sleeping pc. And as mentioned in question I actually do receive the packet. So was the problem the fact that I didn't send a broadcast frame?

Comment: The Frame is broadcast, meaning that the frame is addressed to the MAC address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF. The Packet inside that frame can be addressed to an IP LAN Broadcast (IE: 192.168.0.255 on the net 192.168.0.0/24). so you are port forwarding through a router? Thats probably going to cause issues, since routers reencapsulate the packet and place it in a new frame before passing it on. That changes the nature of the frame, since it is no longer Broadcast, but unicast to the host that the port forward rule indicates. Theoretically it should still work, but may introduce complications.

Comment: `Since the magic packet is only scanned for the string above, and not actually parsed by a full protocol stack` this means, that you does not need higher layer processing to detect packet as magic packet. But this does not means, that valid higher layer packets does not get to higher layer just because them contains valid WoL pattern.